# How to disable the date and time mentioned in the navigator part and not on the x axis in highstock?

Tags: highcharts

It shows the date as 1 Jan and then the time axis starts starting from 00:00:00:010 just above the scrollbar in the navigator not on x axis.On X axis its showing normally what i want.I want to disable that navigator labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable it by [navigator.xAxis.labels](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#navigator.xAxis)

```
navigator: {
            xAxis: {
                labels: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6qC8R/

Comment: Thank you so much.It worked.It disabled the navigator too but i enabled it using enabled:true and it worked.